# Why site security information shows "Connection Is Not Secure",eventhouth web address show HTTPS?

Tags: encryption, https

Is it normal that the site security information always shows "Connection Is Not Secure" on all websites even when the web address shows https.The website identity always shows "This website does not supply ownership information." and verified by as" Not Specified".Is it default that the Technical details always shows"Connection not Encrypted"??

Comment: either the site owner uses a self signed certificate or perhaps this site embeds unencrypted (3rd party) content.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because website uses self-signed certificate, only if you buy certificate from well known companies, web browsers will see your certificate as secure.

Comment: you don't have to buy a certificate: you can easily get a verified one from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).